# Fast way to identify the location the current procedure was called from

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I need to find a way to identify the location that the current function or procedure in a class was called from. It doesn't matter if the result is a memory location or a unit and line number, just something that uniquely the position that the call came from.

The location ID needs to be calculated quickly as it will be used to decide whether or not cached data is available.

For example.

```
type
  TTestObject = class
  public
    procedure TestProc;
    procedure TestCall;
  end;  

...

procedure TTestObject.TestProc;
begin
  TestCall; // "Point A" - Displays "Point A"
  TestCall; // "Point B" - Displays "Point B"
end;

procedure TTestObject.TestCall;
begin
  ShowMessage(SomehowGetTheCallingLineLocation); // Displays "Point A" or "Point B" depending on which line above it is called from
end;

end.
```

"Point A", then "Point B" will be displayed when TestProc is called, no matter how many instances of TTestObject are created or where they reside in memory.

The functionality will be used in the generation of SQL. Currently, I pass a GUID to the call that generates the SQL. This GUID is used to pull the SQL from the cache if it has already been generated.

```
  NewCommand(NewUpdateCriteria('{C43D3B79-9E73-4A4B-9E29-0553542AD0B2}').
    SetValue('AFIELD', AValue).
  Table
    ('ATABLE').
  Where
    (NewSQLComparitor
    ('ID', EqualTo, AID)));
```

The lookup for the call location needs to be fast, otherwise it negates the speed improvements that we should see by caching the SQL.

The component may eventually become open source, so I'm unable to use any commercial third party components. I'd also like to avoid dependencies on open source libraries like JEDI.

Comment: Why not just pass in an argument?  `TTestObject.TestCall(UseCached : boolean);`  Alternatively, whatever object is storing the cached data could keep track of whether or not it has valid data.  ie : `if FCacheDataStore.HasValidData then...`

Comment: I also wonder what you mean by "fast". Do you have specific performance constraints?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I've added a little more information about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: BTW, the ORM may eventually become open source, so I'm unable to use any commercial third party components. I'd also like to avoid dependencies on open source libraries like JEDI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - OK, I've added the comment to the questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your updated question, you only need to be able to identify that one call originated from a different place than another call. In which case you can use the return address to identify caller. And the return address can be obtained by calling the undocumented intrinsic function `System.ReturnAddress`.

This program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure Foo;
begin
  Writeln(IntToHex(NativeInt(ReturnAddress), 8));
end;

begin
  Foo;
  Foo;
  Foo;
  Foo;
end.
```

produces this output on my machine:

```
0041B491
0041B496
0041B49B
0041B4A0
```

Comment: +1 because this directly and effectively answers the question and doubly because I've learned something new as a consequence.  That said, this feels like a really terrible solution to OP's problem - this level of code obfuscation seems completely unjustified given the requirements.  The normal way to get information into a method is to pass it as a parameter.  I see no good reason why this would not work here.  Unless one is writing an exception handler or some such, conditional branching based on a method's return address just feels like a nightmare...

Comment: @J... I agree. This feels like complexity and obfuscation for little disernible gain.

Comment: Also, if the method of checking the return address works then it is demonstrably the case that the correct branch is known at compile time.  If maximizing performance (on the order of the time required to build a query string) is the objective, then simply writing separate methods would be even faster (removing the comparison and branch altogether).  From one line, call `Foo;`, from the other call `FooCached;`.

Comment: @J...-Building complex SQL can be time consuming on a heavily loaded server. The idea is to allow the SQL to be built the first time it is needed, then loaded from a cache on subsequent executions. Knowing where the SQL was built allows us to cache it without the need for passing additional parameters or GUIDs. This does not in my opinion obfuscate the code, but allows us to contain automatic caching logic entirely within the SQL generation classes.

Comment: @norgepaul I understand the motivation, I just refuse to believe that there isn't a better way to achieve your goal.  If I found code of this sort in a database library I would be highly motivated to exterminate it as quickly as possible.  It's simply an awful way to solve a problem like this...

Comment: @J...Feel free to suggest an alternative solution. We've put quite a bit of thought into this and so far this is the best idea we've come up with.

Comment: @norgepaul Based on what information?  I have no idea what your requirements or architecture are.  How you implement this depends entirely on the way you intend it to be used.  I've suggested three methods in comments already.  If they are not suitable, it is not clear from the information in the question why that is the case.

Comment: @J... That's kind of my point. To make statements like "It's simply an awful way to solve a problem like this" without understanding our architecture is a little strong in my opinion. If you're interested, I'd be happy to let you take a look at the code for the ORM we're writing. It's on a private repo on GitHub. I just need your username.

Comment: @norgepaul I can imagine a lot of implementations with a lot of different needs.  I can't imagine any that need *this* as a solution.  If you want to post a new question with a clearly defined scenario, requirements, and this as your attempted solution, I'm sure you would get a lot of valuable feedback.  I don't think I'm going to develop the code for you, though.

Comment: @J... Just so we're clear, I'm not asking you to develop the code for me. I offered to let you look at the code if you were interested in understanding the architecture. I understand that you can't imagine a scenario where this pattern might be used and that's fine. Thank you for your input anyway. Cheers, Paul

Comment: @norgepaul No, but I don't intend to spend a day digging through your source code to generate ideas for you.  That *is* software development, in my mind.  If you're willing to do the legwork of presenting the problem and associated constraints clearly then I (and others, surely) would no doubt be able to offer helpful advice.  The choice is yours.

Comment: I think it is very unusual to use the return address as an input to the function. I don't ever recall seeing that as an idiom. If it's not widely used, doesn't that suggest that it's not a great idea. What's wrong with using arguments? Clear. Explicit. Well understood by all readers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Currently I need to pass in a GUID for each unique SQL statement in order to have an ID to use for the cache. This is potentially very prone to errors. e.g. copy/paste some code and forget to change the GUID. Using the return address (as far as I understand) will remove any chance of this happening and be 100% transparent to the end user of the component. I agree it's an unusual way to get the results I need, but I don't see anything dangerous about it.